# How to add an appendix to an article?

Tags: appendices

I need to add an appendix in an article I'm writing, but I don't really know how to do it. Can somebody explain to me what is the proper way to add it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Your question appear to me to be quite basic. It is mentioned in most of the LaTeX guides here: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner) You might consider reading one of them at least briefly.

Answer (score 72):

The command `\appendix` is included in all basic class files:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
\section{Test 2}

% Activate the appendix
% from now on sections are numerated with capital letters
\appendix

\section{Test 3}
\section{Test 3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But it doesn't show in the table of contents.

Comment: Insert ``\usepackage[toc]{appendix}`` in the preamble.

Comment: Or `bibliography=totoc` when using komascript classes.